# find largest smaller element

Tags: r, list

I have two lists of indices:

```
 > k.start
 [1]    3   19   45  120  400  809 1001
 > k.event
 [1]   3   4  66 300
```

I need a list that contains, for each element of `k.event`, the largest value in `k.start` which is less than or equal to it. The desired result is

```
k.desired = c(3,3,45,120)
```

So, I'm trying to replicate this code, except without a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(k.start){
   k.start[max(which(k.event[i] > k.start))]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See `?findInterval` for such a task; `k.start[findInterval(k.event, k.start, all.inside = T)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
vapply(k.event, function(x) max(k.start[k.start <= x]), 1)
# [1]   3   3  45 120
```